# Using cv::waitKey without having to call cv::namedWindow or cv::imshow first

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am writing a GUI program using Qt and doing some video processing with OpenCV. I am displaying the result of the OpenCV process (which is in a separate thread) in a label in the main GUI thread.

The problem I am having is cv::waitKey doesn't work unless I open a native OpenCV window opened using cv::namedWindow or cv::imshow. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Short example:

```
void Thread::run()
{
    //needed variables
    cv::VideoCapture capture(0);
    cv::Mat image;

    //main loop
    //cv::namedWindow("test");
    forever
    {
        capture>> image;
        if(!image.data)
            break;
        emit paintToDisplay(convertToQImage(image));
        cv::waitKey(40);
    }
}
```

With `//cv::namedWindow("test");` i.e. commented, the program crashes with access violation error.

With `cv::namedWindow("test");` i.e. uncommented, the program displays perfect but there's a window (named test) I don't want or need. Anybody?

Comment: Re-read your question, it doesn't make sense that **with** namedWindow() you have one behavior, and then **with** namedWindow() you have another.

Comment: One is commented, the other isn't

Comment: @karlphillip I have edited to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to use `msleep()`. It's easy to use since it's a member of the class `QThread`.

Just thought i'd update this in case someone with a similar problem finds this thread.

Answer (score 4):

`cv::waitKey()` only works with OpenCV windows, which is not what you are using right now.

I suggest you investigate a QT alternative, most probably `qSleep()`, which is provided by the [QTest](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtest.html) module:

```
QTest::qSleep(40);
```

Comment: Yes I think it's a bit silly that `waitKey()` can't work on it's own. I found the solution: `msleep()`. It's a member of class QThread.

Answer (score 2):

cv::waitkey is part of opencv's gui loop for show window

If you simply want to wait for a key press see [QWaitcondition](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwaitcondition.html).

OR  you could display another named window with no image in it, or a small 1,1 pixel image and just ignore the window

Answer (score 1):

You can call

```
qApp->processEvents();
```

instead of

```
cv::waitKey(40);
```

in the loop to make your application responsive and let the rest of the loop do their job.